# Placing floats from an arrayList into equal width bins to create a histogram

Tags: java

This code will currently take in an array list and create 10 equal width bins from the floats contained; it will then print the bin ranges. What I am having trouble with is figuring out how to index through the ArrayList and print a star in the correct bin according to the float found.

I'm not asking for code; rather a push in the right direction.

```
 public static String getHist( String Tag, ArrayList <Float> x)
{

    Float max = getMaximum(x);
    Float min = getMinimum(x);

    Float interval = (max - min) / 10f;
   // System.out.print("Interval:" + interval);
    Float base = min;
    //System.out.println(Tag);

    //Loops through for 10 iterations
    for(Float i = base ; i <= (max - interval); i+= interval)
    {
        //System.out.print("Interval:" + i + "\n");
        //prints out the bin range
        System.out.print(i + " - " + (base += interval) + " | ");

    //Loop through ArrayList and if a number found belongs within a bin place it
    // within that appropiate bin

    //Logic not correct?
        for(Float index = i; index <= base; index++)
        {
               for(Float n : x)
               {

            System.out.print("*");
               }
        }
        System.out.println();
        }
    return Tag;
}
```

Comment: You need to check that the value of `n` is within the range of the bin before printing your `*`.  You're currently printing a `*` for every value in `x` whether it's in your current range or not.

Comment: Yea I just had that to make sure the *'s printed in the correct spot

Comment: You could create an array of bases and check whether x is greater than or equal to `bases[c]` and less than `bases[c+1]`

Comment: so a base for the max and min of every bin?

Comment: You'll only need the base or the max; you'd do `a >= base[c] && a < base[c+1]` since `base[c+1]` is the upper bound on the previous base.  If you're tracking max, then you change it to `a <= max[c] && a > base[c-1]`.  Each will have it's own constraint on your search for the correct bin (whether you use a binary search on your array or iterate through it or some other heuristic)

Comment: Thank you, this logic helps quite a bit

Comment: In your case, since you're always going to have only 10 bins, you could iterate through and only have to do one logical comparison; `a < base[c+1]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(Float n : x)
        {
            if (i.compareTo(n) <= 0 &&  base.compareTo(n) > 0)
            System.out.print("*");

            else if (i == max && n == max)
            {
                System.out.print("*");

            }
        }
```